# Wordpress Header Image Mobile CSS Issue

Tags: css, wordpress, image, mobile

Working on the following site and can't get the header to resize in mobile properly: http://tinyurl.com/mrveubj

When it is resized on mobile screens it moves to the right and does not remain centered above the navigation as it does on a full size screen. Code is below:

```
#branding .header_logo .tb-image-logo img {
display:block;
margin-bottom:-15px;
margin-left:-15px;
margin-top:-30px;
max-width:990px;!important}
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: What, exactly, is wrong with it? How should it be rendering? What have you tried? Where's the relevant code?

Comment: Edited description above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just only add property width:100% to #branding .header_logo .tb-image-logo img

```
#branding .header_logo .tb-image-logo img {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 990px;
    width: 100%;
}
```